# ionic4 facebook login catches "user" cancelled as error

Tags: typescript, facebook, ionic-framework, native

Before marking my question as duplicate please note that i have seen a similar question and it wasnt answered correctly, the solution didnt work for the person who asked and didnt work for me either.

I am trying to implement ionic native fb login and after doing this

I have checked to see if the user is logged in but the user isnt. Who has a solution please

```
  this.faceBook.login(['public_profile', 'user_friends', 'email'])
  .then((response: FacebookLoginResponse) => {
    this.presentToast("response");
    const facebookCredential = firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider.credential(
      response.authResponse.accessToken
    );
    firebase.auth().signInWithCredential(facebookCredential)
      .then(result => {
        var user = result.user;
        resolve(user);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        reject(err);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    this.presentToast(err);
  });
```

the toast message is "User cancelled". I have no idea why its so. Can someone assist me please

Comment: Please note that i have tried wrapping this in a method that cheks if the user is already logged in or not and no user is logged in

Comment: I am currently having the same issue. Did you find a solution? I will get back with a Answer if you didn't and i find it :)

Comment: I didnt find a solution @ivanSt

Comment: I created a answer with that worked for me. I hope it helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was downgrading the cordova plugin.
I had these versions on the project:

```
"@ionic-native/facebook": "^4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^4.2.1",
```

I removed the ^ to prevent unwanted updates and i downgraded my cordova-plugin-facebook4 to 4.1.0.

```
"@ionic-native/facebook": "4.1.0",
"cordova-plugin-facebook4": "4.1.0",
```

If it doesnt work try looking on the cordova-plugin-facebook4 github release page and checkout the changelog. Maybe that will guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks a lot pal. Ive been stuck here for weeks. Changing my facebook version to 4.1.0 works like charm

Answer (score 0):

try this one because if you have already login it will throw error. you need to first check whether user logged in or not here is sample

```
 this.fb.getLoginStatus().then((res) => {
  if (res.status === 'connected') {
    //console.log('connected', res);
    this.fb.api("/" + res.authResponse.userID + "/?fields=id,email,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender", ["public_profile"]).then((data) => {
      //console.log('data', data.email);

    })
    //


  } else {
    this.fb.login([]).then((userData) => {
      //console.log('note connected', userData);
      this.fb.api("/" + userData.authResponse.userID + "/?fields=id,email,name,picture,first_name,last_name,gender", ["public_profile"]).then((data) => {
        //console.log('data', data.email);

      })
    }).catch((error) => {
      // FB Log in error

      this.util.showErrorAlert('Something went Wrong while login');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I stated that i have checked if the user is logged in and it says the user isnt logged in